# Hibernate validator for chars

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to validate that a Character is either M or F or do I need to use a string with a regex?

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[MF]{1}$", message = "customer.sex.regex")
private String sex;
```

I would like to use

```
private Character sex;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your should this regular expression for accepting only M or F.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[M|F]{1}$", message ="Must be M or F")
```

In your second case of using as Character, you need to validate that this character is whether "M" or "F". Other can be set as sex.

You cannot use `@Pattern` for `Character` variable, You will get below exception.

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could
>   be found for type: java.lang.Character.

Comment: Thanks, I am going for the String.