# How to use Spring/Hibernate validation on a char field?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to use validation on a Character field which should have either a 'Y' or 'N' in it.  I checked for existing answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599069/hibernate-validator-for-chars), but the most common answer seems to be "change the Character to a String and use @Pattern" which I can't do in this case.

Is there an existing validation annotation available for Character values?   I can't seem to find one.  How does one validate a Character field?

Comment: For what it's worth, you may not have a choice if you're being forced to write an ORM wrapper to a legacy database, but what you really have is a `boolean` and should preferably treat it as such.

Comment: Yeah, no choice in this case.   The DB is the DB and it's not going to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `yes_no` type in hibernate.
mapping:

```
<property name="flagField" type="yes_no"/>
```

or

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean getFlagField();
```

This will appear as `Y/N` in the database.

Useful link: http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/type_yesno_hibernate_annotation