# How can I bean-validate on a char?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I just found that [`@Pattern`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) might work (only) with `CharSequence`s.

How can I validate a single char?

```java
//@Pattern(regex = "[YN]") // @@?
private char someYn; // 'Y' or 'N'
```

Will it blend?

Using an [AttributeConverter](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) is not an option.

Oh, is a single `char` also a `CharSequence`?

Comment: @Pattern(regexp = "^[Y|N]{1}$", message ="Must be Y or N")  try this.You cannot use @Pattern for Character variable, You will get exception

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Is `{1}` part necessary? I'm not asking about the `regex`, anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, {1} is necessary to match any character.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 That is not true.  `{1}` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own ConstraintValidator:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html

Where you can provide annotation and validation type 
for which you can define your logic 
And then you can annotate your field with your custom annotation

Here is link with steps how to make it :

https://dzone.com/articles/create-your-own-constraint-with-bean-validation-20

As per javax validation documentation :

@Pattern(regex=, flag=) String.

Additionally supported by HV: any sub-type of CharSequence.

Checks if the annotated string matches the regular expression regex considering the given flag

So actually with Character using @Pattern you will get the error

Thanks

Comment: Sir, request to confirm, `@Pattern` doesn't work for `char`? Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599069/hibernate-validator-for-chars

Comment: Yes as per javax.validation says we cannot use Character